# How to install common lisp with emacs and SLIME when the slime-helper.el is not automatically generated?

Tags: common-lisp, slime

I want to get started with Common Lisp and I follow [this](https://lisp-lang.org/learn/getting-started/) guide to install it on my arch linux machine. However, this call fails:

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/.quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
```

...because there is actually no such `slime-helper.el` file in my *~/.quicklisp-folder*. How do I proceed with normal installation?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t seem to be an emacs question at all.

Did you successfully install the `:quicklisp-slime-helper` package in the previous step? Carefully examine the output in your shell; it should have a message telling you to add the helper to your Emacs init, something like this:

```
slime-helper.el installed in "/home/db48x/.quicklisp/slime-helper.el"

To use, add this to your ~/.emacs:

  (load (expand-file-name "~/.quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
  ;; Replace "sbcl" with the path to your implementation
  (setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

If you don’t see this message, and you see an error message instead, then  you should fix the error indicated in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Using quicklisp to install SLIME is not the easiest way. The easy way is to just `use-package` the emacs slime package : when you run slime inside Emacs, slime will automatically install the common lisp part (called SLYNK) into your common lisp implementation.

Here is my configuration :

```
(use-package slime
  :init
  (progn
    (require 'slime-autoloads)
    (add-hook 'slime-mode-hook
              (lambda ()
                (unless (slime-connected-p)
                  (save-excursion (slime))))))
  :config
  (progn
    (use-package slime-company)
    (setf inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
    (slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-company))
    (setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
    (define-key lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-q") 'slime-close-all-parens-in-sexp)
    (define-key slime-mode-indirect-map (kbd "M-_") 'paredit-convolute-sexp)
    (define-key slime-repl-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-z") #'quit-window)
    (define-key slime-repl-mode-map (read-kbd-macro paredit-backward-delete-key) nil)))
```